# include_blank: false not working in administrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-5, administrate

I've generated the `_form.html.erb` view in `Fields::Belongs_to` to customize the select element but I can't seem to make `include_blank: false` to work. Here is my code. I've already search on the correct syntax of using `include_blank` in select block.

```
<div class="field-unit__label">
  <%= f.label field.permitted_attribute %>
</div>
<div class="field-unit__field">
  <%= f.select(field.permitted_attribute, include_blank: false) do %>
    <%= options_for_select(field.associated_resource_options, field.selected_option) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

*edit: value of include_blank in code*

Comment: Can you try this ? `<%= f.select field.permitted_attribute, options_for_select(field.associated_resource_options, field.selected_option), { include_blank: true } %>
`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I've editted the code since I got a typo, but doing what you suggests with `false` as the value still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you setting `required: true` anywhere ?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag#1353-Showing-the-select-with-a-value-previously-known), I think this happens because of the syntax.

Comment: @JohnBaker If I'd change to using select_tag it raises an error that its undefined method

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I had set the belongs_to in my model as `optional: true`, but even if I'd removed that it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try `= f.select field.permitted_attribute, options_for_select(field.associated_resource_options, field.selected_option), { include_blank: false} , { class: "form-control" } `. Refereing to the signature  `select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block) public`

Comment: I think I've found the reason why it doesn't work, Im gonna try to submit an issue with administrate since I think it's in their codebase, though thanks @JohnBaker

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select(field.permitted_attribute, include_blank: "Choose...") do %>
```